# Java XML to HTML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which contains another XML inside CDATA as follows

```
 ... <report format="CP XML" ><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0"
 encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> ...
```

I need to convert the XML to HTML file by traversing through CDATA.

It is easy to convert simple XML to HTML but how can I convert XML of above kind (within CData).

Is there any way to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at any of XSLT processors? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Comment: Can you provide a more complete sample xml and a snippet of how you would deal with a simple xml?  This is certainly possible, but it will be easier describe working from a base of your current knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First: when you say it is easy to convert simple XML to HTML, what do you mean? Does that mean you have an existing software for this?

Given that, I would expect that you can just extract the inner XML, traverse it, replace it in the outer XML with an empty string, travers the modified outer XML, and then just insert the first generated HTML into the other one.

The question is: what kind of outcome do you expect? I assume you would have a HTML nested into another HTML, which is probably not valid HTML anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to read the XML inside CDATA.

```
<xsl:value-of select="/report"></xsl:value-of>
```

would return you the XML inside CDATA tag and surely you can play around with it.